# Defined a custom action in controllers and added routes but still get no route matches error. Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a links controller and I have defined two custom actions called upvote and downvote. The action definitions:-

```
  def upvote
    @link = Link.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @link.vote_count += 1
    flash[:message]="Vote successfully registered"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @link.vote_count -= 1
    flash[:message]="Vote successfully registered"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I have added the routes for these actions in the routes.rb file:-

```
  post '/links/:id', to: 'links#upvote', as: 'upvote'
  post '/links/:id', to: 'links#downvote', as: 'downvote'
```

rails routes shows:-

```
upvote POST   /links/:id(.:format)     links#upvote
downvote POST   /links/:id(.:format)     links#downvote
```

I'm calling the actions from the view as below:-

```
<% if link.user != current_user %>
  <span class="vote-buttons">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="vote-buttons">
      <%= button_to 'Up', 'upvote_path', type:"button", class:"btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
      <%= button_to 'Down', 'downvote_path', type:"button", class:"btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
    </div>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

But I keep getting this error:-

```
No route matches [POST] "/upvote_path"
```

Why am I seeing this even though rails routes shows that the route exists?

I tried restarting the server too.

Comment: you are defining it as a post request so why are you including :id to the route, you can simply define it like this  => post '/links', to: 'links#upvote', as: 'upvote' and use it like upvote_path

Comment: I need to use the id of the link from the params in the upvote/downvote actions.

Comment: so make it GET request, like this => get '/links/:id', to: 'links#upvote', as: 'upvote' and use it like this => upvote_path(id: link.id)

Comment: Please let me know if it works

Comment: Just tried this, I get "bad URI(is not URI?): upvote_path(id: link.id)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No route matches [POST] "/upvote_path"

As per your routes, you are missing an `:id` which should be sent inside the route.

```
<%= button_to 'Up', upvote_path(link), type:"button", class:"btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
```

Same applies for *downvote*

```
<%= button_to 'Down', downvote_path(link), type:"button", class:"btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
```

Addition to the above problem, you are *not saving* `@link` after a *upvote* or a *downvote*

```
def upvote
  @link = Link.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @link.vote_count += 1
  @link.save!
  flash[:message]="Vote successfully registered"
  redirect_to root_path
end

def downvote
  @link = Link.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @link.vote_count -= 1
  @link.save!
  flash[:message]="Vote successfully registered"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Tried this. Still same error:- Started POST "/upvote_path(link)" for ::1 at 2017-06-06 18:10:36 +0530
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/upvote_path(link)"):

Comment: @rawcode Did you notice that I removed quotes around `upvote_path(link)`? Try again with this!

Comment: *facepalm* Argh, so much pain for the quotes. Thanks a lot pavan!

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= button_to 'Up', 'upvote_path', ...
```

The URL for your button here is literally `"upvote_path"`. Naturally, this url doesn't exist. I think you meant something like this:

```
<%= button_to 'Up', upvote_path(link), ...
```

Comment: @pavan suggested the same, I tried it. Still the same error.

Comment: @rawcode: "Still the same error." - I don't think so. You didn't notice the quotes or read the answer carefully enough.